# Randomly generating a SKSpriteNode based on possible values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

We have two custom subclasses of `SKSpriteNode`.

One is called `circleNode` and the other `triangleNode`. There are three sub types to the circle option, which are created with a custom init method passing in an enum.

For example:

```
enum CircleType: UInt {
    case Circle1 = 1
    case Circle2 = 2
    case Circle3 = 3
}

class TapCircleIcon : SKSpriteNode
{
    convenience init(typeOfCircle: CircleType) {
```

**Within the Game Scene**
Within the game scene we control spawning the sprite nodes. There are 4 different options in total, circle1, circle2, circle3 and triangle.

**Question**
What is the best way in swift, to randomly select one of these sprites to spawn? Depending on the result we could initialise the correct sprite such as `TapCircleIcon(typeOfCircle: CircleType.Circle2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To randomly select something `arc4random` and its friends are nice. My take for the `CircleType`:

```
let ct = CircleType(rawValue: UInt(arc4random_uniform(3) + 1))
```

As described in http://nshipster.com/random/  `arc4random_uniform(N)` delivers a random int between `0` and `N-1`.

Comment: Thanks, I used a variant of this, in fact generating the number first then depending on the number create the let, as number 4 is of a different class per the question